# Why is NPM giving me unmet dependency warnings for dependencies that actually are met?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm

I'm trying to get angular2 up and running with typescript and node, but it keeps giving me warnings about unmet peer dependencies. However, this suggests they are available:

```
tyler@tyler-Blade-Stealth:~/projects/mockups$ npm install -g @angular/core
/usr/share/node/lib
├── @angular/core@2.4.3 
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@^5.0.1
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@^0.7.2

npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.3 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.3 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none was installed.
tyler@tyler-Blade-Stealth:~/projects/mockups$ npm view rxjs | grep version:
  version: '5.0.3',
tyler@tyler-Blade-Stealth:~/projects/mockups$ npm view zone.js | grep version:
  version: '0.7.4',
```

How can I make these warnings go away?

Comment: peer dependencies should be installed manually. So put them to your `package.json` together with `@angular/core`

Answer (score 0):

`npm view` shows information about the package in the registry, not whether it's installed or not.